# Proving question on triangles.

Tags: triangles

I have a question that seems very difficult to solve by myself:

> Question: ABC is a triangle where B=2C. D is a point on BC such that
>   AD bisects BAC and AB=CD. Prove that BAC=72°.

Please help.

Comment: Honestly, I dont know where to start, but I have tried applying the exterior angle theorem to it, but not working...

Comment: In particular, have you tried to draw the situation?

Comment: This is a duplicate of a problem I solved a few days ago.

Answer (score 1):

Let me try.

[image]

Let $BE$ be a bisector of $\angle B$. One then has $\triangle ABE \sim \triangle ACD$. So, $$\frac{AB}{AC} = \frac{AE}{AD} = \frac{BE}{CD}.$$

Moreover, one has $$\frac{AE}{AD} = \frac{AB}{AB+BD}.$$

We get $AC = AB + BD = CD + BD = BC$. So, $\angle BAC = \angle ABC = 2\angle BCA$. Finally, we get $\angle BAC = \frac{2\times 180^\circ}{5} = 72^\circ.$